# How to push correctly a js value in db (dynamic table)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I don't know if my title is completely correct, but I want to know how to send a dynamic information generated by a JS.

My script in PHP:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var i=<?php echo $new_id; ?>;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"<?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::hiddenField('id', "+i+")); ?></td>" +
        "<td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::selectMenu('suppliers_id', $OSCOM_ProductsAdmin->SupplierDropDown())); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::selectMenu('customers_group_id', B2BAdmin::getCustomersGroup('Normal'))); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::inputField('discount_quantity', '', 'placeholder="Qty"')); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::inputField('discount_supplier_price', '', 'placeholder="Supplier Price"')); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::inputField('discount_customer', '', 'placeholder="Without %"')); ?></td>");
      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
      if(i>1){
        $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

the html generated after add a row

```
                                   <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td><table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>id</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">Fournisseur</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">Groupe Clients</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">Range Quantité</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">Prix Fournisseur</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">% Remise Client</th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                           <tr id="tr_0">
                            <td>84 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="84" /></td>
                            <td class="col-md-2"><select name="suppliers_id[84]" id="suppliers_id[84]" class="form-control"><option value="">--Aucun--</option><option value="1" selected="selected">test</option></select></td>
                            <td class="col-md-2"><select name="customers_group_id[84]" id="customers_group_id[84]" class="form-control"><option value="" selected="selected">Normal</option><option value="1">Tarifs 1</option></select></td>
                            <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="discount_quantity[84]" value="1" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="discount_supplier_price[84]" value="5" placeholder="Supplier Price" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="discount_customer[84]" value="3" placeholder="Discount without %" class="form-control" /></td>
                             <td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <div><a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a><br /><br/></div>



<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var i=85;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"<input type='hidden' name='id' value='+i+' /></td>" +
        "<td class='col-md-2'><select name='suppliers_id' id='suppliers_id' class='form-control'><option value=''>--Aucun--</option><option value='1'>test</option></select></td><td class='col-md-2'><select name='customers_group_id' id='customers_group_id' class='form-control'><option value=''>Normal</option><option value='1'>Tarifs 1</option></select></td><td class='col-md-2'><input type='text' name='discount_quantity' placeholder='Qty' class='form-control' /></td><td class='col-md-2'><input type='text' name='discount_supplier_price' placeholder='Supplier Price' class='form-control' /></td><td class='col-md-2'><input type='text' name='discount_customer' placeholder='Without %' class='form-control' /></td>");
      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
      if(i>1){
        $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The result if I try to save the data `$_POST`

```
[id] => +i+ ===>must be a number
    [customers_group_id] => 1
    [discount_quantity] => 50
    [discount_supplier_price] => 50
    [discount_customer] => 50
```

Comment: Please explain what your specific problem is ... see [ask]

Comment: Just I need to send the new value of a new row with +i+ like a number

Comment: use ajax to do that. Shouldn't the id be determined server side?